# Devexpress, traducir los objetos de Devexpress a español

Tags: vb.net, .net, devexpress

quisiera saber cómo traducir los objetos de Devexpress a español, por ejemplo las barras de los reportes.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Ariel, ¿has intentado leer la documentación? --> [Localization Service | DevExpress Help](https://documentation.devexpress.com/LocalizationService/16235/Localization-Service)

Comment: Carlos Muñoz, se hacerlo en C#, pero no encuentro como hacerlo en vb.NET

Comment: Entonces podrías poner al menos el código en C# y mencionarlo para poder traducirlo a VB

Comment: CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;

            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
                                            Ese seria el codigo en C# que se coloca en la clase de Programs.cs, pero en vb mo se donde colocar el codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo agrego esta linea en cada control aunque lo podrias hacer de forma global:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-MX");
```

Comment: Esto es correcto, pero **No es necesario** agregarlo a cada control, solo debe agregar esta línea de código en `Program.cs` antes de invocar el `Application.Run`

Comment: gracias @j.Rodríguez